# Можно ли изменить цвет input-а через css?

Tags: html, css

Присвоил класс *input*-ам.

В *css* меняю цвет через селектор класса — безуспешно:

```
.inp {
    background-color: #ffe; 
    color: #930;
}
```

Comment: Проверьте в developer tools не зачеркнуты ли добавленные стили. Для проверки также можно поставить !important, либо влепить перед классом id, типа `#something-strong .inp`

Comment: И загруженный файл стилей проверьте, у вас может  из кэша грузится

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/php77yu0/

```
.inp {
    background-color: #ffe; 
    color: #930;
}
```

Ваш вариант рабочий.
Проверяйте, что нужный css файл подключается и что он не закеширован. Возможно, что другие стили перекрывают ваши. Пробуйте с другим css-классом или так:

```
.inp {
    background-color: #ffe !important; 
    color: #930 !important;
}
```